# WordPress Gallery Caption Box to accept "Line Breaks" with the enter key

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add HTML elements, and get WordPress's Default Gallery to allow for HTML & "Enter" line breaks.

Primarily I am trying to let WP automatically see there's a line break and echo that out, however it just mashes paragraphs together.

Is there a way to do that without have to do HTML, or is the Caption/Description box in the Image to be treated as markup.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to your child theme's custom style.css to get the gallery captions to honor line breaks:

```
.gallery-caption {
  white-space: pre-line;
  margin-top: -18px;
}
```

The negative value for margin-top is to remove the blank line added before the entire caption.

You can read more [here](https://amethystwebsitedesign.com/add-multi-line-captions-to-wordpress-galleries/).